# out of order write a file python

Tags: file, python-2.7, sockets

I have multiple segments saved in an input file. The format is;

```
  Use case 1:

  host        port    start_byte     end_byte 
 127.0.0.1   12345   0              2048
 127.0.0.1   12346   0              1024
 127.0.0.1   12347   1024           2048

 Use case 2:

 host        port    start_byte     end_byte 
 127.0.0.1   12345   0              2048
 127.0.0.1   12346   1024           2048
 127.0.0.1   12347   0              1024
```

Here, the first line is for the reference to understand what each line has. 
The host is the localhost but ports are different.

Here we have 3 ports. Port #12345 has entire file (say abc.txt). Port #12347 has 
the second segment whereas the port #12346 has the first segment.

Now, I want to read file from the end of file towards the start of file(from line 3 to 1).

The code to download each segment and write to a new file is given below.

```
 def downloadSegment(threadName, fileNameTemp, server_addr, server_port, segment_beginaddr, segment_endaddr, fileName, maxSegmentSize,ip_address,peer_server_port, relevant_path):

      downloadSegmentStr = "download," + fileName + ","+segment_beginaddr+"," + segment_endaddr   
      socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      socket1.connect((server_addr, int(server_port)))
      socket1.send(downloadSegmentStr)

      lock.acquire()
      with open(fileNameTemp, 'ab') as file_to_write:   
          file_to_write.seek(int(segment_beginaddr),0)
          while True:
          data = socket1.recv(maxSegmentSize)
          #print data
          if not data:
            break

          #print data
          file_to_write.write(data)
     file_to_write.close()
     lock.release();
     socket1.close()
```

When I write the segment in increasing order (Use case 1), then, it works perfectly. But, when I try using the `out of order` like explained in above Use case 2, it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You missed these parts of the Python Documentation:

> [open(name[, mode[, buffering]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)
>
> … `'a'` for appending (which on some Unix systems means that *all*
>   writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek
>   position).
>
> [file.seek(offset[, whence])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek)
>
> … Note that if the file is opened for appending (mode `'a'` or `'a+'`),
>   any `seek()` operations will be undone at the next write. If the file is
>   only opened for writing in append mode (mode `'a'`), this method is
>   essentially a no-op…

Thus, mode `'a'` is unsuitable for the task. Sadly, `stdio`'s `fopen()` offers no mode without `a` that creates a file if it doesn't exist and doesn't truncate it if it exists. So I'd use `os.open()` like in:

```
    with os.fdopen(os.open(fileNameTemp, os.O_CREAT|os.O_WRONLY), 'wb') as file_to_write:
```